# Print a specific value of a key in a dictionary list

Tags: ansible

I have an input as such

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "static_plugin_versions": [
        {
            "name": "ace-editor",
            "version": "1.1"
        },
        {
            "name": "analysis-core",
            "version": "1.95"
        },
        {
            "name": "ant",
            "version": "1.9"
        },
        {
            "name": "antisamy-markup-formatter",
            "version": "1.5"
        },
        {
            "name": "apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api",
            "version": "4.5.5-3.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

My aim to to print out the `version` by specifying a particular name. In this case specifically looking for the `version` of `analysis-core`

What I have tried are the following

```
- debug:
    var: static_plugin_versions['analysis-core']['version']

- debug:
    var: static_plugin_versions['analysis-core'].version

- debug:
    var: static_plugin_versions[analysis-core.version]
```

The only thing that works is

```
- debug:
    var: static_plugin_versions[1].version
```

But this is not feasible since if more entries get added to the dictionary, it will break.

Any indication what Im doing wrong here. Am looking for a way that does not rely on looping.

**EDIT**

Just tried this

```
- set_fact: 
    analysis_core_version: "{{ item.version }}"
  when: "'analysis-core' in item.name"
  with_items: "{{ static_plugin_versions }}"

- debug:
    var: analysis-core-version
```

But I get:

```
TASK [copy : set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={u'version': u'1.1', u'name': u'ace-editor'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'version': u'1.95', u'name': u'analysis-core'})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={u'version': u'1.9', u'name': u'ant'})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={u'version': u'1.5', u'name': u'antisamy-markup-formatter'})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={u'version': u'4.5.5-3.0', u'name': u'apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api'})

TASK [copy : debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "analysis-core-version": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Comment: easiest way would be to use a loop, adding a `when` condition to match the `item.name` you need to grab...

Comment: @ilias-sp Thanks. Please have a look at my edit. I tried it but get `VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED`

Comment: Was a typo. Was printing the wrong variable name. Now it works. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with the [selectattr](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#selectattr) filter, which lets you apply a filter to a list of objects.  For example, if I have this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    "static_plugin_versions": [
      {
        "name": "ace-editor",
        "version": "1.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "analysis-core",
        "version": "1.95"
      },
      {
        "name": "ant",
        "version": "1.9"
      },
      {
        "name": "antisamy-markup-formatter",
        "version": "1.5"
      },
      {
        "name": "apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api",
        "version": "4.5.5-3.0"
      }
    ]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "version of {{ item }} is {{ (static_plugin_versions|selectattr('name', 'eq', item)|first).version }}"
      loop:
        - ace-editor
```

The output will be:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=ace-editor) => {
    "msg": "version of ace-editor is 1.1"
}
```

Or, using your example:

```
- set_fact: 
    analysis_core_version: "{{ (static_plugin_versions|selectattr('name', 'eq', 'analysis-core')|first).version }}"

- debug:
    var: analysis-core-version
```

Which produces:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "analysis_core_version": "1.95"
}
```

If necessary, the [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter allows for substantially more complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1 (not optimized)

As suggested by Illias comment, you can use a loop to go other each element in the list, match its `name` value and print its `version` when condition is met.

```
- name: print version of analysis-core
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.version }}"
  when: item.name == 'analysis-core'
  loop: "{{ static_plugin_versions }}"
```

Meanwhile this will go other each element and skip task whenever there is no match. If you have hundreds of plugins, this will soon become unreadable in your ansible execution log.

## Solution 2 (my preferred)

Query your data stucture to get exactly what you need. Your friend here is the [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) (and you should read [jmespath doc](http://jmespath.org/) if you want to go further). For your particular example

```
- name: print version of analysis-core
  debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ (static_plugin_versions | json_query("[?name == 'analysis-core'].version")).0 }}
```

**Notes**:

1. I inferred that your plugin names where unique in your list. Therefore querying for a particular plugin name returns a single element and I can print the first one in list as the expected result.
2. The order of single and double quotes matters in the above example (see [jmespath specification](http://jmespath.org/specification.html): you'll get an empty string result if you switch them around.
3. I used a yaml folded block in my example so I didn't have to escape the double quotes (because I'm a very lazy B@sT@rD :D), but you can use a normal string and escape double quotes if you wish.

Comment: Regarding note 2, the difference has nothing to do with how Ansible casts strings to Python objects, but is in fact due to jmespath syntax, in which single-quoted strings and double-quoted strings are different. See http://jmespath.org/specification.html for details.

Comment: My bad ! I just **totally** mixed-up with [an unresolved bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299#issuecomment-366781707) which as nothing to do with single/double quotes. Thanks for pointing this out, editing my answer.